# Sitecore Multilist with Search and Images

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-mvc, sitecore7.2

I'm using Sitecore 7.2 with MVC. I have a component that has a Multilist with Search field that points to media items. There can be multiple media items here.

Is there a way to make this list editable via the Page Editor?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to use Edit Frames.
These posts describe what they are and how to use them:

- http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2011/11/28/using-sitecore-editframe-in-pageedit/
- http://www.cmsbestpractices.com/how-to-properly-use-sitecore-edit-frames/